# Odd response from actuator/metrics/http.server.requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have this weird response from /actuator/metrics/http.server.requests

```
{"name":"http.server.requests","baseUnit":"seconds","measurements": 
[{"statistic":"COUNT","value":2.0},{"statistic":"TOTAL_TIME","value":0.325170155}, 
{"statistic":"MAX","value":0.250113973}],"availableTags": 
[{"tag":"requiredMetricName","values":["http.server.requests"]}]}
```

And all tags don't work

For example

```
/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=status:200
```

gets 404

I use Spring boot 2

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

I have

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests", true);
    properties.put("management.endpoints.web.exposure.include", "*");
    application.setDefaultProperties(properties);

    application.run(args);
}
```

Comment: How is http.server.requests generated? Are you using Spring MVC, Webflux?

Comment: Do I need to do anything with WebMvcConfigurer? implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had extra bean. It was the reason

```
@Bean
public WebMvcTagsProvider webMvcTagsProvider() {
    return new WebMvcTagsProvider() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Throwable exception) {
            return ((Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entry -> new ImmutableTag(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<Tag> getLongRequestTags(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    };
}
```